# Is there a way to solve quintics of the form $ax^5+bx^4+c=0$?

Tags: closed-form, quintics

It is known that if we only consider the first four decimal digits of the following (no rounding), we have that this holds:$$\pi^4+\pi^5=e^6\label1\tag1$$However, if we use even one more decimal place, we find that it does not, in fact, hold. So obviously, I want to find some $\epsilon$ (for $\epsilon\gt0$, since $\pi^4+\pi^5\lt e^6$) such that $\eqref1$ is true.

In other words, I want to find an $\epsilon$ such that$$(\pi+\epsilon)^4+(\pi+\epsilon)^5=e^6$$which means that I need to find the real root of the quintic$$x^5+x^4-e^6=0\qquad\boxed{\small{\text{Where }e\text{ is Euler's number}}}$$So I want to know if there is a way to solve quintics of the form$$ax^5+bx^4+c=0$$I specifically have in this case$$\boxed{a=1\\b=1\\c=-e^6}$$however if a general form of the quintic is known, that would be appreciated.

Comment: $x^5+x^4-e^6$ has exactly one real root, namely $x=3.14159268251$. So let $\epsilon=x-\pi$. There is no "formula" for a quintic, like for a quartic, cubic or quadratic.

Comment: This might be helpful ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Series_representation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics has a small collection of solvable quintics -- notice that most do *not* have variable coefficients.  For your quintic, you could reduce to $x^5 + bx^4 - c = 0$ since one can just divide through by $a$.  Your specific quintic has one real root $\epsilon = 2.892211149644086830{\dots} \times 10^{-8}$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the closed form [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E5%2Bx%5E4-e%5E6%3D0) with Glasser’s derivation, like on Wikipedia, likely being able to be used to derive it.